# Calculate months between actually month and a specific one

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I've a little question. How I can calculate the months between the current month and another given month? For example: now it's February, I want to know, how many months are between February and let's say January. Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: Needs clarification: Suppose it's December and you want number of months between that and January. Is the answer 1 or 11?

Comment: Yes there are lots of ways to do this, Did you tried anything ?

Comment: If it's December, the number between January should be 1.

Comment: but you can't get this information properly without taking the year into account or making some additional assumptions. If the current month is feburary and the specified one is december, how do you know whether the result should be 2 or 10?

Comment: Check my pseudo-code answer (since you didn't specify any programming language). 

difference is:

    (oy*12 - om) - (cy*12 - cm)

where `cy` is the currentYear, `oY` is the other year, `cm` is the currentMonth and `om` is the otherMonth, and `oy > cy`


Edit: nevermind, just saw you added c#

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your months are encoded like:

```
Jan = 1
...
Dec = 12,
```

the difference will be:

```
int difference = m2 >= m1 ? m2 - m1 : 12 + m2 - m1;
```

where m1 - the first month and m2 - the another one.